# Using .htaccess to redirect requests for updated cached files

Tags: .htaccess, file-rename

A client has changed their branding slightly so I need to update the CSS and favicon. Favicons, particularly, seem to be very strongly cached so, to stop the client from thinking the work hasn't been done, I would like to add a rule in the .htaccess that instructs something like...

*"Take the request for /favicon.ico and instead serve up /favicon2.ico"*

...and a similar rule for the CSS if possible.

I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before but I failed to make a note of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects won't help you with cached requests where the client doesn't make a request to the server at all. The best solution is to change your HTML pages and add a query string with a version number to your favicons and other resources:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css?v=1" />
```

Then you can update the version number whenever the resource changes.

Comment: Simply worded yet totally understandable. I've always wondered what the query was about for inert files like CSS. Thanks :)